# Check for identical values swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to make a memory game where I apply images to 12 different buttons and check if the images are the same when 2 buttons are showing.

**-------------------FINISHED FORM?-------------------------**

Here is a try at Duncan C's suggestion;

```
func setImages() {

    var values = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]
    values.shuffleInPlace()

    button1.tag = values[0]
    button2.tag = values[1]
    button3.tag = values[2]
    button4.tag = values[3]
    button5.tag = values[4]
    button6.tag = values[5]
    button7.tag = values[6]
    button8.tag = values[7]
    button9.tag = values[8]
    button10.tag = values[9]
    button11.tag = values[10]
    button12.tag = values[11]

}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    var images : [UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named:"ye1")!,
        UIImage(named:"ye2")!,
        UIImage(named:"ye3")!,
        UIImage(named:"ye4")!,
        UIImage(named:"ye5")!,
        UIImage(named:"ye6")!,
        UIImage(named:"ye7")!,
        UIImage(named:"ye8")!,
        UIImage(named:"ye9")!,
        UIImage(named:"ye10")!,
        UIImage(named:"ye11")!,
        UIImage(named:"ye12")!
    ]

    images.shuffleInPlace()

    let integrera = (sender.tag - 1)
    let imageString:String = String(format: "ye%i", integrera)

    if !firstButtonAlreadyPresssed {
        firstButtonValue = sender.tag //remember the button for later
        firstButtonAlreadyPresssed = true
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: imageString), forState: .Normal)

    }
    else
        //We already have a first button pressed.
        if sender.tag == firstButtonValue {

        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: imageString), forState: .Normal)

        }
        else {

        let secondimage = (sender.tag)
        let secondString : String = String(format: "ye%i", secondimage)

        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: secondString), forState: .Normal)
        }
        firstButtonAlreadyPresssed = false //reset the "isFirstButton" flag for the next time.
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an array of images. Let's call it `images`. In your buttonPressed method, set sender's image to `images[sender.tag -1]`. For the first button, you probably want to leave the image in place. For the second button press, you want to show the second image, say "you win" or "you lose", pause a few seconds, then revert both the first button and the second button back to their generic images.

Comment: @DuncanC Should I shuffle the array, and should the second buttons image be `images[sender.tag -2]` and so on for all 12 buttons? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @DuncanC Look at the updated code and the question in the comment sector here and I think we will solve this!

Comment: Swift is funny about spaces sometimes. It probably needs to be `button1.setImage(images[sender.tag - 1 ])` instead of button1.setImage(images[sender.tag -1]) (note the space between `-` and `1`. And no, it should not be `tag-2`. Why in the world would that make any sense?

Comment: @DuncanC New error with `button1.setImage(images[sender.tag - 1])` it says -----> Cannot subscript a value of type [UIImage] ---> Where `images` is the problem

Comment: That should work. Break it into 3 separate parts and debug it: First, put `tag - 1` into an `Int` variable. Next, put the image at that index into another variable. Finally, assign the image to the button. (Note, I don't think UIButton has a `setImage` method. I think it's `setImage:forState:`.)

Comment: @DuncanC I don't understand why it should be `sender.tag - 1` Why - 1? I think the code is in a good form, look at the last part for new information.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, there are a bit of lengthy and repetitive code here I believe. You can just add all buttons to the same `@IBAction func`. So you can have one `@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton)` rather than 12 like you have now (I think, since your function is called `@IBAction func button1PRESSED(sender: AnyObject)`). So when you first click a button you store the button, and also store if its the first or second button clicked. When you click the second button you check if it has the same `UIImage` as the first one clicked, otherwise you what ever it is you are supposed to do.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    if self.firstButtonStored == true {
        if self.firstButton.image == sender.image {
            // They are the same    
        } else {
            // they are not the same
        }
    } else {
        self.firstButtonStored = true
        self.firstButton = sender
    }
}
```

I would also recommend storing all the buttons in one `OutletCollection` (works like an array) rather than 12 buttons in self. And I would also use something else than `UIImage` to check if they are the same, not sure if this actually works since you need the image name and not the image itself to make a comparison. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: The unfortunate thing about outlet collections is that the order of the objects in the array is not guaranteed. I've been bitten by this a couple of times. It seems to work, and then at some point the order of the outlets in the array changes out from under you. This is infuriating. If Apple wasn't going to preserve the ordering of the items in an outlet collection they should have made it a set which is unordered, rather than an array. Better yet, they **should** preserve the order of the items!

Comment: @DuncanC If I'm not mistaken they are ordered the way you drag them in. I've never experienced the issue you describe using Outlet collections. And besides, if you are only going to iterate all of them you don't need it to be ordered. Unless you want to access a specific index that should always contain a specific object it doesn't matter. Good pointing it out though, and again - I might be wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

Don't, dont, **DON'T** create 12 separate variables, `card1-card12` and 12 `IBActions` `button1PRESSED`-`button12PRESSED`. This kind of thing where you have lots of exactly the same thing where the only thing that changes is a value is a "**code smell**". It tells you you are doing it wrong.

Instead, you should find a way to do it where you can use the same IBAction for all the buttons, and index into the array rather than having 12 separate variables.

I would suggest using tags on your buttons. Have button 1 use tag 1, button 2 use tag 2, etc.

Then in your IBAction, fetch the tag from the button and use that to figure out which button was pressed and what to do.

You will also need a flag that tells you if this was the first button pressed or the second, so you can tell if you need to test for matches (if it's the 2nd one) or just remember which one was pressed (if this is the first button pressed.)

```
var firstButtonValue: Int
var firstButtonAlreadyPresssed: Bool

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) 
{
  if !firstButtonAlreadyPresssed
  {
    firstButtonValue = sender.tag //remember the button for later
    firstButtonAlreadyPresssed = true
  }
  else
  {
    //We already have a first button pressed.
    if sender.tag == firstButtonValue
    {
      //right answer. Handle it.
    }
    else
    {
      //wrong answer. Handle it.
    }
    firstButtonAlreadyPresssed = false //reset the "isFirstButton" flag for the next time.
  }
}
```

You could have an array of the images to use for each value, and then fetch that image based on the value of `firstButtonValue` or `sender.tag`.

Comment: Hey, I tried using the knowledge you taught me, but still have som issues that I bet you think are easy to solve.. :-) Look at my update if you're still willing to help ;-)

Answer (score 2):

An approach, not a full solution

- Create a struct `Card` with `value` and `index` properties and make it `Equatable` by value.
  You can add more properties like `done`, `status`, `image` or whatever.

  ```
  struct Card : Equatable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let value : Int
    let index : Int
    var description : String { return "Card \(index)"}
  }

  func ==(lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool
  {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
  }
  ```
- Shuffle the values and create an array of 12 cards

  ```
  var values = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]
  values.shuffleInPlace()


  var cards = [Card]()
  for (index, value) in values.enumerate() {
    cards.append(Card(value: value, index: index))
  }
  ```
- Implement a method to find the corresponding card

  ```
  func twinCard(card : Card) -> Card {
    return cards.filter({$0 == card && $0.index != card.index}).first!
  }
  ```
- In Interface Builder assign tags from 0 to 11 to the twelve buttons and connect all buttons to the same `@IBAction`

  ```
  @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let tag = sender.tag
    let chosenCard = cards[tag]
    let otherCard = twinCard(chosenCard)

    // The following depends on the design of the UI          
    // for example get the corresponding button by viewWithTag(otherCard.index)
    // or use an array which holds the button references.

    ...
  }
  ```

Don't shuffle the view, shuffle the model ;-)

Comment: Really good approach, except I wouldn't recommend using tags plainly because I don't like using them. They work, of course, but not my personal preference. This solution is by far the best one yet though :) Try it out